# Strange return type of __get_free_pages

Tags: kernel

Why does it return unsigned long? Why not void* or char*?

```
unsigned long __get_free_pages(unsigned int gfp_mask, unsigned int order)
```

I guess it returns an adress, or have I misunderstood that function completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correct, it returns memory address of a first byte of first page allocated. Funny thing that `page_address()` which is internally used by `__get_free_pages()` actually returns `void*`.

Reason for doing that may be found in [LDD3, chapter 11 (PDF)](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch11.pdf):

> Although you must be careful when mixing different data types, sometimes there are good reasons to do so. One such situation is for memory addresses, which are special as far as the kernel is concerned. Although, conceptually, addresses are pointers, memory administration is often better accomplished by using an unsigned integer type; the kernel treats physical memory like a huge array, and a memory address is just an index into the array. Furthermore, a pointer is easily dereferenced; when dealing directly with memory addresses, you almost never want to dereference them in
>   this manner. Using an integer type prevents this dereferencing, thus avoiding bugs. Therefore, generic memory addresses in the kernel are usually unsigned long, exploiting the fact that pointers and long integers are always the same size, at least on all the platforms currently supported by Linux.

Answer (score 2):

"From the memory-management point of view, the system's RAM can be seen as a linear array of pages, so it can make a certain amount of sense to think of addresses as integer types — indexes into the array, essentially. Integers can also be used for arbitrary arithmetic; pointers in C can be used that way too, but one quickly gets into "undefined behavior" territory where an overly enthusiastic compiler may feel entitled to create all kinds of mayhem. So unsigned long was established as the return type from get_free_page() and, in general, as the way that one refers to an address that may appear in any place in memory." -- from https://lwn.net/Articles/669015/ -- Please read this interesting story about unsigned long vs. void *  :-)